# Using org-mode as a flat file database and sanitizing input

Tags: database, emacs, org-mode, bookmarks

I'd like to use an org-mode file as a flat file database that can be edited both programmatically and by hand. An example follows showing a list of bookmarks.

```
* Somebody's blog :: I like org-mode
:url: http://somebody.com/org
** Quotation 1
:date: 2013/01/13 08:32:11 EST
Very interesting observations here.
** Quotation 2
:date: 2013/01/13 08:33:46 EST
A marvelous code snippets

* Man bites dog
:url: http://newssite.com/today
```

I'd like emacs or a webserver cgi-script or similar to edit such a file (in the example above, to add more bookmarks or more quotations to existing bookmarks).

The problem is when, e.g., accepting arbitrary selections from websites to insert under an org-mode heading, it becomes necessary to sanitize the input so that, at minimum, quoted lines starting with asterisks don't affect the file's structure: if a quotation starts with "* this is pathological example", and is inserted into the file under some heading, when I open the file in emacs, it'll appear as a new first-level (h1) heading.

How can I meet the twin goals of (i) an editable org-mode flat file database (this rules out escaping and all our XML tricks) and (ii) isolating arbitrary inputs?

- anti-solution: #+BEGIN_QUOTE wouldn't work because lines starting with "* " are rendered as new headings.
- possibility 1: box/rebox everything from the outside world: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BoxQuote this seems excessive though.